# Wordpress blogging breaking when no user is logged in

Tags: wordpress

I've got a blog setup in wordpress and I'm using the free Typebased theme. Something I've noticed is when im logged in as admin everything will work great but when I logout and the view the site as a regular member things get buggy. below are my screenshots:

Logged in:
[image]

Not logged in:
[image]

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Comment: Did you try to disable your plugins ?

Comment: I only have one plugin enabled other than the wordpress importer. I disabled the one and yet still nothing.

Comment: here are my errors: http://i46.tinypic.com/2hi7708.png

Comment: that's weird, now it is doing it when i log in too. let me see if disabling that plugin had anything to do with it

Comment: Yeah it fixed it in the admin section when i re-enable Front-end Editor. that's the problem. would deleting that plugin maybe fix it?